# How to select(fetch) all the <select> elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fill in all the options for things like

```
<select id=such_a_field>
```

to get the inputs in my form I can just go

```
$inputs = $('#myFormName :input');
```

and iterate through them and set the value based on the id.
For my select field, which I am now upgrading from a simple input to restrict what the user can put in, I first want to go read the set of available options (from the DB, via ajax of course), and then set the right one based on what's in the DB. Unfortunately

```
$selects = $('#myFormName :select');
```

produces

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: select
```

as of course :select isnt a pseudo selector. It would be enough just to extend my above :input selector and then enhance my field setting code to handle selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

```
$('#myFormName select')
```

`select` is a tag, so you must query for it as it is. `:selected` will give you the selected `option`s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)

```
$selects = $('#myFormName select');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a collection of all select tag input within your form, do this:--

```
$selects = $('#myFormName select');
```

Comment: Sorry, : got there by mistake.

Comment: Be careful next time, it's the little detail that matters.